# Firefox won't run java after installing 15.04

Tags: firefox, java

I installed ubuntu 15.04 yesterday. Firefox will not run the race viewers at igpmanager.com which use java. Ran java version and it returned the latest version of java. This machine is running an SSD drive. An update java applet appears briefly and then disappears leaving the race viewer black screen.

On my 64 bit computer the igpmanager viewer runs normally after the upgrade to 15.04.

Could the SSD be causing a problem with my older computer?  7 year old Toshiba with Centrino duo cpu and 4 gig ram laptop 5200

Comment: What packages did you exactly install?